# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: any

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, use-state

I got an error on the code below:

```
const [capturedImage, setCapturedImage] = React.useState<any>(null)
```

please help.

Comment: please share you complete code

Comment: Maybe you have not imported React?